# How to make animation?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a web page similar to my prototype design (https://xd.adobe.com/spec/79bbc862-6b2f-4f46-4c27-c5847918f854-0f8a/screen/8e80c8c1-a016-4e2c-8e11-557ebdf778b5/success-17)

i have made the page with all the text and everything jus stuck on the loader part

Comment: Please show us your attemps and the relevant part of your code. If you don't know how to make an animation with css , online you can find a lot of tutorials. Here nobody will code for you

Answer (score 0):

You want to use javascript/jquery for this. A simple method would be

`$('#text').delay(3000).fadeIn(2200);});`

but you can play around with the delay and the fade